# How do you use a function inside arguments in haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, arguments

I am on a problem that asked to write a function that applies a function to an Integer and calculate the answer. Here is the problem:

Declare the type and define a function that takes a function (say f) and an integer (say n) and returns f 0 + f 1 + f 2 + … + f n. For example, fun sq 5 would returns 55 which is 0+1+4+9+16+25 (“sq” means “square”).

Does anyone know how to do that? I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

This is called a higher order function

```
fun :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
fun f n = ???
```

And we just use `f` like a normal function, writing `f 0` or whatever. ??? is the haskell translation of

```
 f 0 + f 1 + ... + f n
```

As for how to do this, this looks like homework so I'll just hint you to look at using `[0..n]` to get a list from 0 to `n` and

```
map :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int] -- restricting for clarity
```

which applies a function to every item in a list (hey it's another higher order function)

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int
```

Which adds up all the numbers in a list.

Comment: +1 But can't the type be generalized to `Num a => (Int -> a) -> Int -> a` ? (Though I agree this homework question is likely expecting your answer)