# How to change values of a function in Haskell and return this function?

Tags: function, haskell

I would like to do the following in Haskell:

```
myFunc 1 = 0
myFunc 2 = 1

changeMyFunc:: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)
changeMyFunc x y z = undefined

-- change value of function x at position y to value z and return this function
-- this would make: (changeMyFunc myFunc 1 5) 1 == 5
```

This is how far i got it:

```
changeMyFunc2:: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)
changeMyFunc2 x y z | y == z = myFunc
                | y /= z = myFunc where myFunc y = 12
                | otherwise myFunc
```

the last line causes: parse error on input '|'
How can i check multiple cases using where?

Comment: This looks like an exercise.  What have you attempted first?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I do not know how to change a value.
returning it as a function is not a problem though.
I tried returning another function that is identical to the first function, but it differs in that one given position.

Comment: `|`s need to line up.

Comment: @Cubic I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: @Cubic They actually don't. `|`s aren't given any indentation block. (*Except* with the `MultiWayIf` syntax extension, where they had to add one for sanity when nesting them.)

Answer (score 2):

When defining `changeMyFunc x`, the first step would be to just return the original `myFunc x` itself. That gets you almost the whole way there.

Then divide that into two cases: one case where `x == y` and the other case where `x /= y`, where `y` is your special input. What should `changeMyFunc x` return in each case?

### Updated hint

Currently you are accepting args `x`, `y`, `z`. Try something with this instead:

```
changeMyFunc f y z x
    | fill this part in yourself
```

`f` is the original function.
`y` is the special input and `z` is the special output.
`x` is the argument for the new `changeMyFunc` function that you're defining.

> See [How do you use a function inside arguments in haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598675/how-do-you-use-a-function-inside-arguments-in-haskell?rq=1) for more information on higher-order functions.

Think about which args you should be comparing, and what the output should be in each case. (Hint: I already gave part of the answer above.)

Then you can test it with this:

```
*Main> let successor = (+) 1
*Main> let successor' = changeMyFunc successor 1 1000
*Main> successor' 100
101
*Main> successor' 101
102
*Main> successor' 500
501
*Main> successor' 1
1000
```

### Solution

> `changeMyFunc :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)`
>  `changeMyFunc f y z x`
>    `| x == y = z`
>    `| otherwise = f x`

Comment: This helped me alot and its almost working. The key was to use the "where" function.
However, i cannot use the "|" operator in combination with where somehow.
The fist line seems to work out, but every following line produces this error: "parse error on input '|'

Comment: @MeterPaffay `where` clause should go **after** all the guards.

Comment: @zudov i thought i could use 'where' to evaluate the return value.
It seems this is not possible. How can I manage to do this.
To make it clear: i try to return a function that differs in only one given position.

Comment: @MeterPaffay I am not sure what you mean by "evaluate the return value", but the purpose of `where` is to create additional definitions which would be available only in scope of the definition in which `where` is used.  Multiple guards constitute single definition, so there can be only one `where` for a chain of guards.

Comment: I'll be glad to provide an answer with an explanation of these issues if you'll change the question to address specific problems.